# Get the value of particular column via stored procedure in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My stored procedure has a select statement ie: 
`select * from studenttable where studentid=@studentid`

Student table further has columns `studentid, name, city`

When I enter student id in a textbox it should fetch the name and city and display in LabelName and LabelCity respectively.

What I've done:

```
        bool attempt = dl.OpenSQLConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("VerifyStudent");
        cmd.Connection = dl.myConn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENTID", studentid)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
```

Comment: what is problem?

Comment: @Always_a_learner I want to check if my username column has 'ABC' , if yes then navigate to 'creategame.aspx' page like I've done in first part if the question

Comment: do you want to validate password also in same sp or different sp than ValidateAdminLogin?

Comment: @Always_a_learner Validate username and password also in the same stored procedure

Comment: Side note: You should also use parameterized queries in the first case. But be aware that ["AddWithValues is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And passwords should not be stored as clear text but only a hash of them.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you want to check whether user name 'ABC' or any user name exist or not. This sp will return value greater than zero count if required username and password match. Pass 'ABC' or any user name as username parameter.

```
create procedure ValidateAdminLogin
(@UserName varchar(50),@Pasword varchar(50))
as
begin
select count(*) from user_creation where user_name=@UserName and password=@Pasword 
end
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to alter the  Stored procedure. Updated the question

Comment: So where are you looking for solution? i mean at database end or in code?

Comment: if you are allowed to create new sp , then you can create new sp that will return page name where authenticated user should navigate..let me know if this is your case